# Android Studio Нажатие на иконку меню "Поиск" срабатывает только со второго раза

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
    return true;
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // получим идентификатор выбранного пункта меню
    int id = item.getItemId();
    // Операции для выбранного пункта меню
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_search:
       searchView.setMenuItem(item);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    if(query.length() > 0)
                    {
                        Search(query.toUpperCase());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AppGlubina = 0;
                        loadSpisokLayout();
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        case R.id.email:
            AlertDialog.Builder buil  = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            buil.setMessage("Если у Вас есть вопросы, пишите! Электронный ящик: System@gmail.com");
            buil.setCancelable(false);
            buil.setPositiveButton("Написать письмо", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whitch){

                    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"System@gmail.com"});
                    email.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Выберите почтовый клиент"));

                }});
            buil.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whitch){
                dialog.cancel();
                }});
            AlertDialog ale1 = buil.create();
            ale1.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Кнопка `Поиск` в `Android Studio` или в вашем приложении?

Comment: нет, в приложении

Answer (score 1):

Обработчик события включится только после первого нажатия на пункт меню. Я обычно в таких случаях выношу установку события в метод create